# Does positive correlation of vectors depend on the inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, inner-products, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $v^Tw>0$.

Does $v^TBw \ge 0$ for **every** symmetric positive-definite matrix $B$?

---

I think the answer is negative; this is connected to the fact that the product of symmetric positive-definite matrices is not necessarily positive-definite:

Here is an example where $v^TBw =0$. The question is whether this $v^TBw$ could be **strictly negative.**

Set
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad
\text{ and } \quad 
B = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then
$$AB = \begin{bmatrix} 12 & 5 \\ 7 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

$A,B$ are symmetric positive-definite.

$$AB+(AB)^T= \begin{bmatrix} 24 & 12 \\ 12 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$
which is singular. Thus, there exists a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$
\big(AB+(AB)^T \big)w=0.
$$
Set $v:=Aw$. Then
$$
v^Tw=w^TAw>0,
$$
but
$$
v^TBw=w^TABw=\frac{1}{2} w^T\big(AB+(AB)^T \big)w=0.
$$

Comment: it's equivalent to ask it for diagonal $B$, but you can see that if there's a negative addend in $v^Tw$ you can exploit it

Comment: for example $v=(-1,1)$, $w=(1,2)$, $B = diag(100000,1)$

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I was thinking too complicated...

Comment: I turned your comment into a CW answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Exodd commented, the answer is negative: Take for example
$$
v=(−1,1) , w=(1,2), B=\text{diag}(100,1).
$$

More generally, since positive definite matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable, the problem is reducible or equivalent to considering positive diagonal matrices $B=D$:

In that case the assumption is
$$
v^Tw=\sum_i v_iw_i>0.
$$
and the question is whether or not
$$
v^TDw=\sum_i \lambda_iv_iw_i>0,
$$
for any positive $\lambda_i$.

Thus it is clear that if there is an index $i$ such that $v_iw_i<0$, one can magnify its impact by choosing very large $\lambda_{i}$ to make the inner product negative.